# Easy way to import classes in app.module.ts

Tags: angular, angular-material, ng-modules

I have an Angular 8 project with a standard app.module.ts and I am using many components from Angular Material.
Everytime I use a new componenttype, I have to add it in the app.module.ts twice.

```
[...]
import {
MatButtonModule,
MatCardModule,
MatInputModule,
MatSnackBar} from '@angular/material'       <---- First time
[...]
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
       [...]
    ],
    imports: [
    [...]
        MatButtonModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatSnackBar                          <----- Second time
    ],
    [...]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

That sucks, and I think I saw some code once, where somebody created something like an object from the imports and than just added the object to the NgModule-Imports. Does anybody know what I am talking about?

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio Code there is an extension called Auto Import https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport that does what I believe you are asking. It works by starting to type the component you want to add where you put the arrow for 'second time' and it will populate the options in a drop down you select the one you want it will autocomplete and add the import above. Im not sure if thats what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a module named shared and put all of those components/module and service in it (such as MatInputModule/MatSnackBar and ...),
then, import the shared module wherever you need those components.

For more information: https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-module-tutorial-application-structure-using-modules/